# jQuery AJAX load of content, the loaded content behaves like a separate document

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got a webpage where I want to load a content with Ajax without realoading which I did, however I want the code to work on links from the loaded content as well. As far the loaded content seems to behave as a separate document(if i click a link on a loaded content itopens a new window) which is not my intention here.

js file

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".zoom").hover( zoomIn );
    $(".zoom").mouseout( zoomOut );
    $(".zoom").click( select );
    function zoomIn() {

            $(this).animate({
              left:'10px',
              height:'190px',
              width:'190px',
            });
            $(this).css({"border-radius": "110px"});

    }
        function zoomOut() {
            $(this).animate({
              left:'-10px',
              height:'140px',
              width:'140px'
            });
            $(this).css({"border-radius": "90px"});

    }
            function select() {
            $(this).css({"border":"8px #e53cc7 solid", "border-radius": "110px"});
            $(".zoom").not(this).css({"border":"none"});

    }
    function getRandom(num){
        var my_num = Math.floor(Math.random()*num);
        return my_num;
    }
}); //End document.ready()
$(function () {
//ajax load of main div content specified in links  
       // attaching click handler to links
    $("a.loadnew").click(function (e) {
        // cancel the default behaviour
        e.preventDefault();

        // get the address of the link
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        // getting the desired element for working with it later
        var $wrap = $('#ajax-main');

        $wrap
            // removing old data
            .html('')

            // slide it up
            .slideUp()

            // load the remote page
            .load(href + ' #content', function () {
                // now slide it down
                $wrap.slideDown();
            });
    });
});
```

The main html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Winter Olympics' Champions</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="description" content="Educational apps for Android devices, smartphones, tablets. Language learning, coding, studying, various subjects." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Android app, educational, language learning, self study, mobile devices, smartphone, tablet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/stylewinter.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="tagline">
            <h1>Winter Olympics' Champions</h1>
            <h2>the best in their category</h2>
        </div>
    </header>

    <nav>
        <div id="wrapper">
                <a class="loadnew" href="loadcontent/skiing.html"><img class="zoom" src="images/alpineskiing.png" alt="alpine skiing" /></a>
                <a class="loadnew" href="loadcontent/biathlon.html"><img class="zoom" src="images/biathlon.png" alt="biathlon" /></a>
                <a class="loadnew" href="loadcontent/bobsleigh.html"><img class="zoom" src="images/bobsleigh.png" alt="bobsleigh" /></a>
                <a class="loadnew" href="loadcontent/icehokey.html"><img class="zoom" src="images/icehokey.png" alt="ice hokey" /></a>
                <a class="loadnew" href="loadcontent/luge.html"><img class="zoom" src="images/luge.png" alt="luge" /></a>
                <a class="loadnew" href="loadcontent/skating.html"><img class="zoom" src="images/skating.png" alt="skating" /></a>
    </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="contentwrapper">
        <div id="ajax-main">

        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
    </footer>
    <script src="scripts/my_scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
<div id="content"><a class="loadnew" href="loadcontent/figure.html">content1</a><br/><a class="loadnew" href="loadcontent/speed.html">content2</a><br/><a class="loadnew" href="loadcontent/shortspeed.html">content3</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow *load()* behaved funny, so i substituted it with plain old *$.get()*. I've also modified your code and used delegation (just like I mentioned in my first answer) to bind click events to all *a.loadnew* (you can later move JS from here to a separate file, like you used to have it):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Winter Olympics' Champions</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="description" content="Educational apps for Android devices, smartphones, tablets. Language learning, coding, studying, various subjects." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Android app, educational, language learning, self study, mobile devices, smartphone, tablet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/stylewinter.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="tagline">
            <h1>Winter Olympics' Champions</h1>
            <h2>the best in their category</h2>
        </div>
    </header>

    <nav>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <a class="loadnew" href="loadcontent/skiing.html"><img class="zoom" src="images/alpineskiing.png" alt="alpine skiing" /></a>
            <a class="loadnew" href="loadcontent/biathlon.html"><img class="zoom" src="images/biathlon.png" alt="biathlon" /></a>
            <a class="loadnew" href="loadcontent/bobsleigh.html"><img class="zoom" src="images/bobsleigh.png" alt="bobsleigh" /></a>
            <a class="loadnew" href="loadcontent/icehokey.html"><img class="zoom" src="images/icehokey.png" alt="ice hokey" /></a>
            <a class="loadnew" href="loadcontent/luge.html"><img class="zoom" src="images/luge.png" alt="luge" /></a>
            <a class="loadnew" href="loadcontent/skating.html"><img class="zoom" src="images/skating.png" alt="skating" /></a>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="contentwrapper">
        <div id="ajax-main">
            Shit
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
    </footer>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() { //ready function
            $(".zoom").hover( zoomIn );
            $(".zoom").mouseout( zoomOut );
            $(".zoom").click( select );

            //ajax load of main div content specified in links  
            // attaching click handler to links
            $("#wrapper, #ajax-main").on("click", "a.loadnew", function(e) {
                // cancel the default behaviour
                e.preventDefault();

                // getting the desired element for working with it later
                var $wrap = $('#ajax-main');

                $wrap.html('')
                    // slide it up
                    .slideUp();

                // load address of the link    
                $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(resp) {
                    $wrap.html(resp);
                    $wrap.slideDown();
                });
            });
        });

        function zoomIn() {
           $(this).animate({
                left:'10px',
                height:'190px',
                width:'190px',
            });
            $(this).css({"border-radius": "110px"});
        }

        function zoomOut() {
            $(this).animate({
                left:'-10px',
                height:'140px',
                width:'140px'
            });
            $(this).css({"border-radius": "90px"});
        }

        function select() {
            $(this).css({"border":"8px #e53cc7 solid", "border-radius": "110px"});
            $(".zoom").not(this).css({"border":"none"});
        }

        function getRandom(num){
            var my_num = Math.floor(Math.random()*num);
            return my_num;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried that solution doesn't work for me. The html document i link to has only the div i've posted previously and the main html document has a nav with series of links of the same class.

Comment: Why not apply the same concept to the whole document then? _$(document).on("click", "a.loadnew", function(e) { ... }_

Comment: You mean to the main html I load content into? When i change $("a.loadnew").click(function(e) to $(document).on("click", "a.loadnew", function(e) even the first content that loads the links opens as another document.

Comment: Sorry, i lost the track here... What is #ajax-main? Is it the body of your document? If so, then each of of the linked documents must contain the _$(function() { ... });_ javascript so that, when it's loaded, a new event will be bound to the _a.loadnew_. Alternatively, you can try putting the _on("click", "a.loadnew")_ into the head.

Comment: #ajax-main is just a div in a document. That's what i was thinking, that i need to make all of the loaded html documents a full html webpage with javascript linked and everything. It's just sad it needs to be so complicated. :/ It's as if the loaded content is not recognized as the part of the original html.

Comment: Have you solved your problem yet? If, as you say, _#ajax-main_ is just a div in the document, then delegation should work very well. Im not sure why it's not working for u. Btw, what does "href + ' #content'" mean in your load() function?

Comment: nope, still nothing :/ I will just paste my whole html here and js cause I probably have done smth stupid there or smth...

Comment: I've modified your code and updated my answer. Plz take a look

Comment: Wow awesome! Thx :D Could it be related to the version of js i linked to then? Anyway thank you for help, appreciated :)

Comment: Might be the jQuery version. No idea :) Just glad it worked out. You are welcome.